# Why Wix MSI doesn't include the source files and looks for source files somewhere else?

Tags: wix

I have used Wix on and off for almost a year. After a little break and now I am back to wix and need to build a wix Msi again but I found a very strange thing that I haven't met before. After I created the msi file and and copy the msi to somewhere to install. During the installation, it shows an error that it can't find the source files from the folder: current msi location\EasyLobby\Cogito. I was wondering why it tried to find the source files from that location. I then found that from the project during the compilation, it always creates \EasyLobby\Cogito under the bin\Debug folder. So if I run the msi right from the ...bin\Debug, it runs OK because the \EasyLobby\Cogito folder is there. \

It seems so strange. The msi file should include all the source files and shouldn't look for source files somewhere else. Here is the product.wxs file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

<Product Id="*" Name="SetupCogito" Language="1033" Version="2.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Microsoft" UpgradeCode="96cb03c9-6a03-4344-b816-20a0bb9e5df0">
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="no" InstallScope="perMachine" />

<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
<Media Id="1" Cabinet="Server.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
<!--<MediaTemplate />-->

<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupCogito" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroup"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="EasyLobbyCogitoShortcut" />
</Feature>
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="Files\LicenseAgmt.rtf"/>

<UIRef Id="CogitoUI_Installdir" />

<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="COGITOFOLDER" />
<Binary Id="banner_bmp" SourceFile="Files\Banner.bmp"/>
<Property Id ="PIDTemplate" >
  <![CDATA[&&&-&&&&&&-&&&&-&&&&]]>
</Property>

<Icon Id="ELCogitoConfig.exe" SourceFile="..\CogitoIntegration\ELCogitoConfig.exe" />
  </Product>

<Fragment>
<Binary Id="CustomActions"
       SourceFile="..\CustomActions\bin\Debug\CustomActions.CA.dll" />

   <CustomAction Id="IsValidKeyCode"
              BinaryKey="CustomActions"
              DllEntry="IsValidKeyCode"
              Execute="immediate"
              Return="check" />    
   <InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="IsValidKeyCode"
        Before='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
   </InstallExecuteSequence>

   </Fragment>


  <Fragment>
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="EasyLobby" >
      <Directory Id="COGITOFOLDER" Name="Cogito"/>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>

 <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="EasyLobby Cogito" />
  </Directory>

</Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
 <DirectoryRef Id="COGITOFOLDER">
  <Component Id="EasyLobbyCogitoShortcut" Guid="{BFE6EB30-0F71-4F92-8D93-84B4EBF41F0E}" >
    <File Id="Easy" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\ELCogitoConfig.exe" />
    <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"  Name="Cogito Configuration"    Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder"
      WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Icon="ELCogitoConfig.exe" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes"/>
  </Component>
 </DirectoryRef>
```

And this is the config for heat in project file:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<PropertyGroup>
  <DefineConstants>SourceDir= C:\Development\SetupCogito\CogitoIntegration;</DefineConstants>
  <LinkerBaseInputPaths>..\CogitoIntegration\</LinkerBaseInputPaths>
</PropertyGroup>
<HeatDirectory OutputFile="CogitoSetup.wxs" Directory="..\CogitoIntegration" PreprocessorVariable="var.SourceDir" DirectoryRefId="COGITOFOLDER" ComponentGroupName="ComponentGroup" SuppressCom="true" SuppressFragments="true" SuppressRegistry="true" SuppressRootDirectory="true" AutoGenerateGuids="false" GenerateGuidsNow="true" ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line here is your problem:

```
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="no" InstallScope="perMachine" />
```

Change `Compressed=no` to `Compressed=yes` and it will include all the source files in the finished MSI.  If you don't compress it, the finished files are not included in the MSI and you get an error if it can't find them at runtime.

See [Package reference](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/package.html).

Comment: Thank you so much. That did it! Don't know why it was NO. A simple thing cost me hours but you saved me!